# How to refresh div after AJAX request in MVC?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure how to refresh data after I use AJAX. Here's what I already have:

Frontend:

```
@model TFU.Model.DB_USER

    <div id="listTelNumbers">
        @foreach (var item in Model.DB_USER_PHONES)
        {
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    @item.PHONE
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <button id="removeButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sendRequestToRemove('@item.USER_ID', '@item.PHONE')">Usuń</button>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        }
    </div>
```

Script - `fadeOut` works fine but I don't know what should I `fadeIn`. So I guess is missing a small part of code there.
Also how can I `fadeOut` only the record which I currently removing instead all list.

```
 <script>
        function sendRequestToRemove(id, phone) {
            var data = {
                "USER_ID": id,
                "PHONE": phone
            }


            $.ajax({
                url: '/User/RemoveTelNumber',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (err) {
                    alert('Error: ' + err.statusText);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#listTelNumbers').fadeOut(800, function () {
                        form.html('#listTelNumbers').fadeIn().delay(2000);
                    });
                },
                async: true,
                processData: false
            });
        }      
    </script>
```

Backend:

```
public bool RemoveTelNumber(DB_USER_PHONES model)
{
    var user = db.DB_USER_PHONES.First(x => x.USER_ID == model.USER_ID && x.PHONE == model.PHONE);
    db.DB_USER_PHONES.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to remove `<dl>` element containing the button you clicked from the `<div id="listTelNumbers">` element after the ajax call?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, exactly. Button and Phone number from `<dt>`. In this example (http://prntscr.com/bf25u1) after i'll click `Remove` then in div listTelNumbers will left 3 elements.

Comment: OK, Will add answer shortly - there are a few changes you need to make.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your loop is generating duplicating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. And you should not be polluting your markup with behavior - use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Change the html to remove the `id` attribute, add a `class` name for selection and add `data-*` attributes for the values to be posted

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DB_USER_PHONES)
{
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@item.PHONE</dt>
        <dd><button class="btn btn-default delete" data-id="@item.USER_ID" data-phone="@item.PHONE">Usuń</button></dd>
    </dl>
}
```

Then change the script to

```
var url = '@Url.Action("RemoveTelNumber", "User")'; // always use Url.Action()
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('dl');
    var data = { user_Id: $(this).data('id'), phone: $(this).data('phone') };
    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            // fadeout, then remove
            container.fadeOut(800, function() { $(this).remove(); })
        } else {
            // Oops - display an error message?
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        // Oops
    });
});
```

And finally, change the action method to return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveTelNumber(DB_USER_PHONES model)
{
    var user = db.DB_USER_PHONES.First(x => x.USER_ID == model.USER_ID && x.PHONE == model.PHONE);
    db.DB_USER_PHONES.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true);
    // or if something went wrong, return Json(null);
}
```

I also recommend you rename you classes and properties to follow conventional naming practices - `UserPhone`, not `DB_USER_PHONES`, `UserId`, not `USER_ID` etc.

Comment: If you have time, again I have similary problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854410/how-to-change-priority-of-elements-using-javascript-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Partially reload that div

```
$("#listTelNumbers").load(location.href + " #dl-horizontal");
```

Or reload the entire page w/o refreshing it

```
$(document.body).load(location.href);
```

For a complete reference I found a demo here [Partially load a div without refreshing page in javascript and php.](http://javascriptsolution.com/partially-load-a-div-without-refreshing-page-in-javascript-and-php/?ckattempt=2)

Comment: First example doesn't work, second example refresh entire page, but i'd like to refresh only `div="listTelNumbers"`

Comment: If there is any parent element above #listTelNumbers then try this
$("#parentelement").load(location.href + "#listTelNumbers");

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to find the `<dt>` element which was marked for deletion and fade it out(or remove it completely from the DOM):

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/User/RemoveTelNumber',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    error: function (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err.statusText);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        var dtCollection = $("dt");

        for (var i = 0; i < dtCollection.length; i++) {
            var text = $(dtCollection[i]).text();
            text = text.trim();

            if (text == phone) {
                $(dtCollection[i]).parent().fadeOut('slow');
                //$(dtCollection[i]).parent().remove();
            }
        }
    },
    async: true,
    processData: false
});
```