# How to change priority of elements using javascript in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have to make in my application function for changes the priority of deputy for each consultant. This is what I have already:

View:

```
@model ML.Domain.DAL.DB_CONSULTANTS
....
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID deputy</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.OrderBy(x => x.PRIORITY))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.DEPUTY_ID</td>
            <td>@item.PRIORITY</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default up" data-consultant-id="@item.CONSULTANT_ID" data-deputy-id="@item.DEPUTY_ID" data-priority="@item.PRIORITY">UP</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default down" data-consultant-id="@item.CONSULTANT_ID" data-deputy-id="@item.DEPUTY_ID" data-priority="@item.PRIORITY">DOWN</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default delete" data-consultant-id="@item.CONSULTANT_ID" data-deputy-id="@item.DEPUTY_ID" data-priority="@item.PRIORITY">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Script (atm. only for removing deputy):

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("RemoveDeputy", "Consultant")';
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var container = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = { consultant_Id: $(this).data('consultant-id'), deputy_Id: $(this).data('deputy-id'), priority: $(this).data('priority') };
        $.post(url, data, function (response) {
            if (response)
            {
                // fadeout, then remove
                container.fadeOut(800, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            } else
            {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveDeputy(DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY model)
{
    consultantRepository.RemoveDeputy(model);
    return Json(true);
}
```

And I should add to this script simillary function, if user will click button `UP` or `DOWN` then same data as for `DELETE` will send to backend and there I will change Priority for example in this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ChangePriorityToUp(DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY model)
{
    var deputyForChangePriority = db.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.Find(model.DEPUTY_ID);
    deputyForChangePriority.PRIORITY -= 1;

    if (db.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.Any(x => x.PRIORITY == deputyForChangePriority.PRIORITY + 1)) // +1 because I decrease before
    {
        var deputyToRefresh = db.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.First(x => x.PRIORITY == deputyForChangePriority.PRIORITY + 1);
        deputyToRefresh.PRIORITY -= 1;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true);
}
```

And of course I have to refresh this table at view :) As you see, I have a problem with make javascript function to do this. I think the rest is enough good.

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make script in JS, and of course avoid DRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the POST method so that you can use it for changing the `PRIORITY` either up or down.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePriority(int deputyId, int priority)
{
    var model = db.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.Find(deputyID);
    if (model != null)
    {
        model.PRIORITY = priority;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true);
    }
    return Json(null);
}
```

Then change the html to

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.OrderBy(x => x.PRIORITY))
{
    <tr data-consultant-id="@item.CONSULTANT_ID" data-deputy-id="@item.DEPUTY_ID" data-priority="@item.PRIORITY">
        <td>@item.DEPUTY_ID</td>
        <td>@item.PRIORITY</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default up">UP</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default down">DOWN</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default delete">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then the script will be

```
var priorityUrl = '@Url.Action("UpdatePriority", "Consultant")';
$('.up, .down').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var deputyId: row.data('deputy-id')
    var priority = row.data('priority')
    if($(this).hasClass('up')) {
        priority++;
    } else {
        priority--;
    }
    $.post(url, { deputyId: deputyId, priority: priority }, function(response) {
        if(response) {
            row.children('td').eq(1).text(priority);
            row.data('priority', priority);
        } else {
            // Oops
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        // Oops
    });
});
```

Comment: It's almost good, but I can increase/decrease priority only once, later doesn't work.

Comment: See update (just a matter of updating the value of the `data-priority` attribute in the success callback.

Comment: Yes. And I have to refresh this table also. You know, position of them. `@foreach (var item in Model.DB_CONSULTANT_DEPUTY.OrderBy(x => x.PRIORITY))`

Comment: Did you add only `button.data('priority', priority);` because i getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: button is not defined`?

Comment: You missed `var button = $(this);` :)

Comment: Refreshing the table row orders is an different issue and its going to depend on some factors such as what if after editing, there a 2 rows with the same priority - should the one you just edited be before or after the other one with the same priority etc.

Comment: Heh still weird, because if I press UP (from 2 to 3) then DOWN value is 1 instead 2.

Comment: So maybe better way is just refresh page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114839/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dipix).